# HTML Hyperlinks Fail: Coding Clash?

Tags: html, css

I've been learning HTML & CSS for the past week with basic tutorials and have been trying to recreate a website I made years ago with Squarespace (an easy builder). Yesterday I couldn't add a link to an image, but having achieved that by adding div tags, the rest of my links now don't work. Is there a clash in my coding? Here it is:

```css
<style type="text/css">
  body {background-image: url(THX1138.jpg);
   background-size: cover; background-position: inherit}
  h1 {text-transform: uppercase;height:70%;width: 100%; display: flex; position: fixed; align-items: center;justify-content: center; font-family: helvetica}
  table {text-transform: lowercase;height:90%;width: 100%; display: flex; position: fixed; align-items: center;justify-content: center; font-family: monospace;}
  a:link{text-decoration: none; margin: 2px; color: black;}
  a:visited{color:black}
  a:hover{background-color: #f7d8d8; padding: 3px;
   -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
   -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
   -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;}
  #twitterbird {height: 102%; width: 100%;display:flex;position:fixed;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  
 </style>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 
 <h1>The Alcoves</h1>
 
<table width="50%" cellspacing="20">
 <tr>
  <a href="index.html"><td> Reviews</td></a>
  <a href="index%203.html"><td> Features</td></a>
  <a href="index%202.html"><td> About Us</td></a>
 </tr>
</table>

<div id="twitterbird"><a href="https://twitter.com/AlcovesFilm">
 <img src="twitter%20bird.png" height="40" width="40" alt="Twitter">
</a></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any and all help mightily appreciated!

EDIT: I realise the href is on the wrong side of the td. I was just messing around trying for a fix and forgot to change it back. Think the problem is with the div covering the other links, but I need the div to get the img into the right position and to get the link on the img to work properly. Any ideas?

EDIT 2: Figured it out. I was misinterpreting what div actually is. With height and width I was changing the size of the div not its location, which I hadn't realised. All I needed were top & left commands. Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: Have you tried [validating your html](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: It's only saved as a personal file so I can't validate it yet

Comment: Use the "validate by direct input" option

Comment: Have you read my edit? Any solutions on that theory?

Comment: Right click the link and choose "select element". If the dev toolbar comes up with anything other than the `<a>` tag hilighted, then you have css issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have set the `#twitterbird` div to cover the entire page. The links *are* working, but they are being covered up by the div in question, so the mouse can’t 'get to' the links.

As other posters have noted, you also need to move your `<a>` tags inside of the `<td>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your `a`tags shouldn't be outside the `td`tags, but inside.

```html
<table><tr><td> <a href="index%202.html"> About Us</a></td><tr></table>
```

Comment: While this is definitely good practice, it does not answer the OP’s question.

Comment: @Ryan Well, to be clear, it's invalid HTML to do it the other way, not just bad practice.

Comment: I think he's missing the starting `<a>` altogether on the `<img>`

Comment: @Rob How that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made hasty mistake. change your code with this below.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> <a href="index%202.html"> About Us</a></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
<tr>
    <a href="index.html"><td> Reviews</td></a>
    <a href="index%203.html"><td> Features</td></a>
    <a href="index%202.html"><td> About Us</td></a>
</tr>
```

you should have

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="index.html">Reviews</a></td>
    <td><a href="index%203.html">Features</a></td>
    <td><a href="index%202.html">About Us</a></td>
</tr>
```